# C - Summation with Double - Precision

Tags: c, double, precision

I have problem with precision of **double format**.

---

*Sample example:*

```
double K=0, L=0, M=0;
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &K, &L, &M);
if((K+L) <= M) printf("Incorrect input");
else printf("Right, K=%f, L=%f, M=%f", K, L, M);
```

---

*My test input:*

K = 0.1, L = 0.2, M = 0.3 -> Condition but goes to **'else'** statement.

---

How I can correct this difference? Is there any other method to summation?

Comment: Here we go again... Please read the following document before attempting any more programming with floating point: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @PaulR We could ask in meta to add as a new reason for closure "Doesn't know IEEE 754 Binary Floating-Point format" :-)

Comment: The real question is: why would you expect that program to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the world of Double Precision IEEE 754 binary floating-point format (the ones used on Intel and other processors) `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004` :-) And `0.30000000000000004 != 0.3` (and note that in the marvelous world of `double`s, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3 don't exist as "exact" quantities. There are some double numbers that are very near them, but if you printed them with full precision, they wouldn't be 0.1, 0.2 and 0.3)

To laugh a little, try this: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float

Insert a decimal number and look at the second and third row, it shows how the number is really represented in memory. It's for Delphi, but `Double` and `Single` are the same for Delphi and for probably all the C compilers for Intel processors (they are called `double` and `float` in C)

And if you want to try for yourself, look at this http://ideone.com/WEL7h

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double d1 = (0.1 + 0.2);
    double d2 = 0.3;

    printf("%.20e\n%.20e", d1, d2);

    return 0;
}
```

output:
3.00000000000000044409e-01
2.99999999999999988898e-01

(be aware that the output is compiler dependant. Depending on the options, `0.1 + 0.2` could be compiled and rounded to 0.3)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike integer values floating point values are not stored exactly the way you assign values to them. Lets consider the following code:

```
int i = 1; // this is and always will be 1
float j = 0.03 // this gets stored at least on my machine as something like 0.029999999
```

Why is this so? Well how many floating point number exist in the interval between 0.1 and 0.2?
An infinite number! So there are values which will get stored as you intended but a hell of a lot of values which will be stored with a small error.

This is the reason why comparing floating point values for equality is not a good idea. Try something like this instead:

```
float a = 0.3f;
float b = 0.301f;
float threshold = 1e-6;

if( abs(a-b) < threshold )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Comment: "_Well how many floating point number exist in the interval between 0.1 and 0.2? An infinite number!_" Entirely irrelevant. There are  infinitely many natural numbers, yet the representation of any natural number doesn't take infinite memory. We do not want to represent "all" real numbers.

Comment: While it is true that each natural number can be represented with a finite amount of memory, it is also true that there for a given *fixed* amount of memory exists a natural number whose representation does not fit in said memory. Your point about not wanting to represent all real numbers is precisely the point: We *cannot* represent every real number, and thus every scheme will have problems of the type the original question asks about, namely *there are real numbers that cannot be represented in a given scheme*.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many real numbers between any two distinct real numbers. If we were to be able to represent every one of those, we would need infinite memory. Since we only have finite memory, floating point numbers need to be stored with only finite precision. Up to that finite precision, it might be not be true that 0.1 + 0.2 <= 0.3.

Now, you really should go read what's at the other end of the excellent link provided by Paul R.

Comment: But his program would work as expected if only `double` had de decimal representation, **just as we usually write numbers on paper**. "Infinite" (or unlimited) memory is **not** needed: we do not need infinite paper space to write a decimal number. You can program a data-type with decimal representation if you want. You will have to use named functions like `dec_add`, `dec_mult`... in C, in C++ you could use operator overloading to keep the usual `+`, `-`, `*`... infix syntax.

Comment: His particular example would work, but decimal representation would suffer for other numbers. How would you store 1/3 exactly with finitely many terms in decimal representation? You would indeed need to store an infinite amount of data.

Comment: Again, you do _not_ need unlimited paper space to write "1/3". If you need to store 1/3 exactly, again, do it just as you would do on paper: **store "1/3"**, not "0.333333333....". It depends on what you need to represent exactly: describe your needs, then choose (or implement) the appropriate data-type.

Comment: By storing "1 over 3", you're not storing the decimal representation of 1/3. You are, in fact, storing a fractional representation. I agree that if you only need very limited types of real numbers, you can get away with some special scheme, but in general you would need unlimited memory. To summarize with examples: IEEE 754 can't store 0.1 exactly. Decimal can't store 1/3 exactly. Ratios of integers can't store pi exactly. A ratio scheme can store any rational number exactly as long as the integers describing the ratios aren't limited. But they *are* limited by memory. There's no free lunch!

Comment: "_By storing "1 over 3", you're not storing the decimal representation of 1/3._" Exactly. "_I agree that if you only need very limited types of real numbers, you can get away with some special scheme, but in general you would need unlimited memory._" No, you don't. "_Ratios of integers can't store pi exactly._" If you need to "store pi exactly", you can store it as "pi" (or as something less _ad hoc_). Again, it all depends on **what you need to do**. "_There's no free lunch!_" True: with every scheme designed to "represent exactly" more real numbers, there is additional code complexity.

Comment: "_I agree that if you only need very limited types of real numbers, you can get away with some special scheme, but **in general** you would need unlimited memory._" For any real numbers you'd want to represent, one can define a computer representation. But numbers will not always have a canonic representation. And sometimes comparisons (<, >, ==) will not even terminate!

Comment: Right, I agree. You can avoid the problem by essentially storing a formula for computing the number in question, say pi, but you gotta agree that in that case you've only shifted from the situation of requiring infinite storage to requiring infinite processing time (in such a world you might see OP asking why his program `if (x == y) {...}` runs forever if `x` and `y` both happen to be pi). But technically you are right and I do agree :)

Comment: "_but you gotta agree that in that case you've only shifted from the situation of requiring infinite storage to requiring infinite processing time_" I agree. This approach may not be so useful, but is fun to program. ;)